# split a file into segments?

Tags: bash, file, text, split

I have a file containing text data which are separated by ***semicolon ";"***. I want to separate the data , in other words split where ***;*** occurs and write the data to an output file. Is there any way to do with bash script?

Answer (score 4):

You most likely want `awk` with the FS (field separator variable) set to `';'`.

Awk is the tool of choice for column-based data (some prefer Perl, but not me).

```
echo '1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10' | awk -F\; '{print $3" "$5}'
```

outputs:

```
3 5
8 10
```

If you just want to turn semicolons into newlines:

```
echo '1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10' | sed 's/;/\n/g'
```

outputs the numbers 1 through 10 on separate lines.

Obviously those commands are just using my test data. If you want to use them on your own file, use something like:

```
sed 's/;/\n/g' <input_file >output_file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -d ';' ITEM; do
    echo "$ITEM"
done
```

Comment: This is, to my knowledge, the only efficient way to do this using bash alone; i.e. without resorting to using an external program to do the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cat original_file.txt | cut -d";" -f1 > new_file.txt
```

This will split each line in fields delimited by ";" and select the first field (-f1).
You can access other fields with -f1, -f2, ... or multiple fields with -f1-2, -f2-.

Comment: cat is not needed.   cut -d ";" -f1 org_file.txt > newfile

Comment: Cutting multiple fields leaves the delimiter in place between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate a character to another character by the **'tr'** command.

**cat input.txt | tr ';' '\n' > output.txt**

Where **\n** is new line and if you want a tab only you should replace it with **\t**